# JQuery animate DIV and keep in center

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following code to demo of my form box that i would like to animate out:

http://jsfiddle.net/sv33r/1/

The JS code is:

```
$(".login-form").click(function() {
    $(".login-form").animate({width:500, height: 300});
    $(".footer").animate({width:430, height: 95});
});
​
```

HTML is:

```
<div id="wrapper">    
    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Logo here</h1>
        <span>test</span></div>

        <div class="content">
            blah    
        </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Click to test grow" class="register" />
        </div>    
    </form>
</div>​
```

Currently it just re-sizes without re-centering it on screen.

What do i need to add in order to do this?

Comment: We need your CSS to also see what's going on.  A JSFiddle example will also be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using that #wrapper div, better apply animation to that element. Like this:

```
$("#wrapper").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").animate({width:500, height: 300});
    $(".footer").animate({width:430, height: 95});
});
```

​
Then, in your css remove the following rule from ".login-container": 300px (you dont need this because you are defining this same width at "#wrapper" element)

[Here is the example in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sv33r/5/)

Comment: It needs to be the **.login-form** in order for it to work correctly. I took out a lot of stuff that was inside the **.login-form** div (like a background image behind the box, etc) and using the **wrapper** causes it to warp and not move the form box very much.

Answer (score 1):

change the css #wrapper width: 300px to min-width: 300px
from

```
#wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

to

```
#wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```